# Cleaning up old job object in windows

Tags: winapi

Scenario

(1) My process  has constant JName = "jobName".

(2) Process starts and writes to registry [Key = Pjob, Vlaue = "jobName"], if these values don't already exist. [ This is done so a another process on the machine called R, will periodically look for a job object with the name "jobName", and apply certain job memory limits to this job, if not already done]

(3) Process creates a job object with the name 'jobName',

(4) Process assigns the current process to jobName.

Suppose we start off with process P ,that goes through (1),(2),(3),(4) and then crashes.
The process is woken up by service fabric as P1 and tries to goes through (1) (2) (3) (4)

At (3) , when P1 attempts to create a job object with the name jobName, I believe it is actually getting back the existing handle to the job created by P.

'If the object existed before the function call, the function returns a handle to the existing job object'

At (4) At this point Assigning p1 to the job object fails with the below error

```
Unhandled exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (5): Access is denied.
   at Win32Wrappers.AssignProcessToJobObject(IntPtr jobHandle, IntPtr processHandle) in \Win32Wrapperscs.cs:line 100
   JobObjectUtils.CreateJobObject() in 
   JobObjectUtils.cs:line 28
   at Program.Main(String[] args) in Program.cs:line 98
```

Question:

How can I clean up the old job object created by P and start with a fresh new one when P1 is running? [ The name of the job object has to remain the same]

Comment: Have you tried [TerminateJobObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/jobapi2/nf-jobapi2-terminatejobobject)?

Comment: Your `lpJobAttributes` of `CreateJobObjectW` may result the error. The process P1 's token cannot access the existing job object. It could be the process P1 and the job object [have different session ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/jobapi2/nf-jobapi2-assignprocesstojobobject#parameters).

Answer (score 0):

According to [AssignProcessToJobObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/jobapi2/nf-jobapi2-assignprocesstojobobject), ***All processes within a job must run within the same session as the job.***
Your existing job object created by P is in session 1 while the process P1 created by a service is in session 0. So, access is denied.
Your service should use [CreateProcessAsUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasuserw) or equivalent to create the process P1.